# Zygote unable to obtain gradient: Mutating arrays is not supported

Tags: arrays, machine-learning, julia

By looking at some `Flux` examples, I cobbled together this logistic predictor. However, when evaluating the gradients, I get an error, `Mutating arrays is not supported`. I've tried to make `loss` and `predict` much more concise, even tried to make loss and predict into a single line.

How can I get the gradient for this predictor?

Error:

```
Mutating arrays is not supported

Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] (::Zygote.var"#459#460")(::Nothing) at /Users/john/.julia/packages/Zygote/pmW1K/src/lib/array.jl:67
 [3] (::Zygote.var"#1009#back#461"{Zygote.var"#459#460"})(::Nothing) at /Users/john/.julia/packages/ZygoteRules/OjfTt/src/adjoint.jl:59
 [4] _typed_hcat at ./abstractarray.jl:1335 [inlined]
 [5] (::typeof(∂(_typed_hcat)))(::Array{Float64,2}) at /Users/john/.julia/packages/Zygote/pmW1K/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [6] reduce at ./abstractarray.jl:1377 [inlined]
 [7] (::typeof(∂(reduce)))(::Array{Float64,2}) at /Users/john/.julia/packages/Zygote/pmW1K/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [8] predict at ./In[9]:2 [inlined]
 [9] (::typeof(∂(predict)))(::LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}) at /Users/john/.julia/packages/Zygote/pmW1K/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [10] loss at ./In[10]:2 [inlined]
 [11] (::typeof(∂(loss)))(::Float64) at /Users/john/.julia/packages/Zygote/pmW1K/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [12] #9 at ./In[11]:1 [inlined]
 [13] (::typeof(∂(#9)))(::Float64) at /Users/john/.julia/packages/Zygote/pmW1K/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [14] (::Zygote.var"#50#51"{Zygote.Params,Zygote.Context,typeof(∂(#9))})(::Float64) at /Users/john/.julia/packages/Zygote/pmW1K/src/compiler/interface.jl:177
 [15] gradient(::Function, ::Zygote.Params) at /Users/john/.julia/packages/Zygote/pmW1K/src/compiler/interface.jl:54
 [16] top-level scope at In[11]:1
```

Code:

```
import Flux
import Flux.NNlib
import Zygote
import Parameters

nsamples = 4
nfeats = 5
nlabels = 3
X = rand(nsamples,nfeats)
Y = rand(nsamples,nlabels)
W = rand(nlabels,nfeats)
b = rand(nlabels)

function predict(x)
    return NNlib.σ.( reduce(hcat,(map(i -> (x[i,:]'*W')' + b,1:nsamples))) )  
end

function loss(x,y)
    yhat = predict(x)'
    return sum((y - yhat).^2)
end
gs = Flux.gradient(() -> loss(X,Y), Flux.params(W,b))
```

Shorter loss function (gets the same error):

```
function lossShort(x,y)
    return sum((y - NNlib.σ.( reduce(hcat,(map(i -> (x[i,:]'*W')' + b,1:nsamples))) )' ).^2)
end
gs = Flux.gradient(() -> lossShort(X,Y), Flux.params(W,b))
```

Comment: This doesn't run with your sizes, but maybe `reduce(hcat,(map(i -> (x[i,:]'*W')' + b, axes(x,1)))) ≈ W * x' .+ b`? The simpler form is much more likely to work.

Comment: @mcabbott Not sure what I was supposed to do, but I replaced `NNlib.σ.`'s argument with your suggestion (the part before the `≈`). `predict` compiles, but the `gradient` line fails in the same manner as in the post :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually comes up if you have an array that can be changed using a parameter, or that is a return from a function inside the gradient code. *Note that when I encountered these errors I was still using Julia 1.5.3*

I'm not sure which version of Flux/Zygote do you have, but your code runs fine for me on 1.6

```
(@v1.6) pkg> status Zygote
      Status `~\.julia\environments\v1.6\Project.toml`
  [e88e6eb3] Zygote v0.6.10

(@v1.6) pkg> status Flux
      Status `~\.julia\environments\v1.6\Project.toml`
  [587475ba] Flux v0.12.2
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm updating from 1.4.0 to 1.6.1. I'll be back once I test this

Comment: I have now julia 1.6.1, and installing the packages gave me Zygote v0.4.22, Flux v0.8.3. Trying the code cell gives me an error related to `back!`, but tweaking `lossShort` with `lossShort2(x) = lossShort(x,Y)` finally gives me a tracked vector.

Does the code run with `loss` or `lossShort` for you? How did you get those Zygote and Flux versions?

Comment: I ran your code with `loss`, the versions are the up-to-date flux and zygote versions (at the time of writing) you might have some project requirements that need an older version or you might need to run `] up`